# Login Fail after moving database and website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am relocating a website and database from azure to a local server (sql server 2008 r2).
I successfully copied the database and set up the website in IIS.  I can navigate to the website fine, but it won't logon on.

My Stack Trace

```
Message: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.)
```

Stack trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(SNIHandle handle, SNIPacket packet, UInt32& sniError, Boolean canAccumulate, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsLogin(SqlLogin rec)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate)
   at System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat)
   at System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password)
   at EbpWebSite.Account.login.Page_PreLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Am I missing something?  Did the move screw up the password salts for the login?  My login tables are a standard aspnet_Membership, Roles, Users setup. I just copied from Azure to local DB. The first line would indicate, I got my connection strings updated correctly.

As suggested adding connectionString

```
<add name="EbpCloud" connectionString="Server=EBP-OCON-SQL1;User ID=dbread22;Password=*****;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=True;Connect Timeout=0;Database=EbpReporting;" />
```

The original string was Server=tcp:server.database.windows.net

The website resides locally on the same server as the DB. (Do I need to have local as part of server name?)
my login code:

```
      if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, passWord)) {
    FormsAuthentication.Initialize();
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
    using (var conn = Utilities.SqlConnectionEbp(Utilities.DatabaseEbp.EbpReporting)) {
      // call stored procedure to get the user default session settings
      using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("aspnet_UserDefaultSessionSettings", conn)) {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", userName));
        // Check Sql State and open connection
        if (!conn.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Open))
          conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (reader.Read()) {
            Session["userName"] = userName;
            Session["forceResetPassword"] = passWord.Equals("p@ssw0rd");
            Session["displayName"] = reader["displayName"].ToString();
            Session["instanceId"] = Convert.ToInt16(reader["instanceId"]);
            Session["userEmail"] = reader["email"].ToString();
            Session["userId"] = new Guid(reader["UserId"].ToString());
            //Session["clinicList"] = Utilities.GetClinicList();
          }
        }
      }
    }
    Response.Redirect("/administration/supplierinvoice.aspx", false);
  }
```

The called Utilities class:

```
      public static class Utilities
  {
    public enum DatabaseEbp
    {
      Ebp, EbpReporting, Master, ebpCIS
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// SqlConnectionEBP - EBP Connection object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>SqlConnection</returns>
    public static SqlConnection SqlConnectionEbp(DatabaseEbp database) {
      var connString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EbpCloud"].ToString());
      connString.InitialCatalog = database.ToString();
      var conn = new SqlConnection(connString.ToString());
      return conn;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it is the simple things.  The website and the database both reside on the same physical server so changed connectionstring to

```
  <add name="EbpCloud" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=ebpreporting;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dbread22;Password=*****" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

can you publish your *connectionStrings* tag from *web.config* file, and your code_behind (where you connect to a database)? I never tryed to use standard authentication, but I suspect that it used some server-oriented functions (as you said errors have been displayed after you move to azure server)

Comment: added, and the error occurred after moving OFF Azure. It works fine there just not local.

Comment: I never had similar situation caz' I never used Azure... Sorry